# qbs build: TypeError: Result of expression 'lib' [undefined] is not an object

Tags: c++11, qbs

I'm having a strange problem:

1. I have a cmake-built submodule that will produces some static libraries (named A1, A2, A3) (I followed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49021295/add-submodule-built-with-cmake-in-qbs-project))
2. I write some source code to wrap A then build it as static library B by qbs
3. I have a program C which depends on B to run testing

When I build by qbs command line, it runs well. However, when I build by Qt Creator 4.3.1, it reports:

`creating libB.a
TypeError: Result of expression 'lib' [undefined] is not an object
The following product could not be built for configuration qtc_Desktop_de89834-debug:
C`

I click on the error, it link to Qt/Qt Creator.app/Contents/Resources/qbs/share/qbs/modules/cpp/gcc.js (line 379). I tried to log by add more a log line (i.e. `console.warn(libraryDependencies.libraries`), then it logs out an array of libraries:
`libA1.a,libA2.a,libA3.a,libB.a,,`
I don't know why it appears an empty one at the end. Mention that A1, A2, A3 & B are enough for the build of C.

Can anyone here just help? I'm using Qt 5.9.1 on MacOS

**Updates**:
Everything works on Qt Creator 4.5, so I just move to Qt Creator 4.5 :))

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Qt Creator 4.3, as well as the qbs version it contains (1.,8), are no longer supported, so it makes little sense to investigate this further. Updating is the correct solution.